# site.css not overriding bootstrap.css for .field-validation-error

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC form (with layout page _Layout.cshtml) using jQueryVal. When I submit with empty required fields the validation message displays properly BUT the style in Site.css is not being applied (overriding bootstrap.css). I suspect it is because jQueryVal is running client side. The only way I've found to make it work is to place the actual style on the _Layout page.

```
BundleConfig.cs
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css","~/Content/Site.css"));
```

Site.css

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

_Layout.cshtml (This style block works but not when placed in Site.css)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")

    @*TODO site.css not overriding validation error text color*@
    <style>
            .field-validation-error {
                color: red;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
        </style>
```

Rendered Tags
[image: Rendered Tags]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this page in IE and the style for red validation errors worked fine. Apparently, in Chrome, with a .cshtml utf-8 meta data header, it expects the .css file to be utf-8 as well. Who knew?? I opened a new document in Notepad++, making sure it was utf-8, pasted my .css content, saved it overwriting existing .css and LIKE MAGIC! IT WORKS! :)

Answer (score -1):

In layout.cshtml you have used !important, but in site.css no - have you tried to use it in site.css? If yes, have you tried cascade css, e.g.

```
body .field-validation-error {
    color: red !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Comment: I've tried it both ways. It still doesn't render red.